# How to set zero margins of the figure - matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to crop the figure to have no white space where nothing is plotted? Why  plt.tight_layout(pad=0) does not work? The picture draw 3d coordinate system.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,3])
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

ax.set_ylim(-2,3)
ax.set_zlim(-1,2)

vleng = 5
aleng = vleng/3.

p = np.array([vleng+200, 0, 0])
q = np.array([0, vleng-2, 0])
r = np.array([0, 0, vleng-3])

ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], p]).T, color='black')
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], q]).T, color='black')
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], r]).T, color='black')

ax.azim = 20    # y rotation (default=270)
ax.elev = 20    # x rotation (default=0)
ax.dist = 10    # zoom (define perspective)

ax.set_axis_off( )  # hide all grid

plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

The output:

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhcEW.png)

Comment: you can try playing with `plt.xlim`, `plt.ylim` and `plt.zlim` to get tight coordinates, so that no space is free and axes' limits are the limits of you data

Comment: I tried it, but I wasn't successful. Does another way (easier) exist? plt.tight_layout(pad=0) works in other my scripts.

Comment: can you paste an image of what you're seeing?

Comment: I pasted it to question

Comment: the reason there is so much white space is because you have set `ax.set_axis_off()`. This doesn't mean that the axes are not drawn at all, rather, it is hidden. If you comment that line you'll see that the entire area is being used and the whitespace actually has some content

Comment: Oh, yes and how is the command that axes are not drawn at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried multiple things. The only thing that would reduce these white spaces would require the three lines to be drawn along the meeting lines of the planes. So I did some measurements and here's the code where the white spaces have significantly reduced. You're free to reduce it further by tweaking it some more. Also comment out `ax.set_axis_off( )` to see what's happening:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,3])
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')


ax.set_ylim(0,3)
ax.set_zlim(0,2)
# ax.set_xlim(0,2)

vleng = 5
aleng = vleng/3.

p = np.array([vleng+200, 0, 0])
q = np.array([0, vleng-2, 0])
r = np.array([0, 0, vleng-3])

ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], p]).T, color='black')
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], q]).T, color='black')
ax.plot(*np.vstack([[0,0,0], r]).T, color='black')

ax.azim = 20    # y rotation (default=270)
ax.elev = 20    # x rotation (default=0)
ax.dist = 10    # zoom (define perspective)

ax.set_axis_off( )  # hide all grid

plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much and how to add a line to the script? I tried: `plt.plot([0, 1, 1],[0, 1.5, 1.5])`